# En una Row uso ConsumerWidget coloco dos ImputGeneric pero al validar uno de ellos se expande al tamaño de Row pero el otro no. Se ve descuadrado

Tags: flutter

> Hola si me pueden ayudar con un tema con Fluuter, Tengo Un formulario con imputs en un
> Column que contiene 2 RowS, cada una de estas es un ConsumerWidget,  Uno tiene Dos > Imput,
> al saltar la validacion la coloca debajo , esto se expanden a toda la Row y la row se > descuadra,
> ya que el otro campo no se expende

```
    /*Una columna con dos filas  */

    class DataInputs extends StatelessWidget {
      final CatalogModel? maritalStatusCatalog;
      const PersonalDataInputs({Key? key, this.maritalStatusCatalog})
          : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(children: [

          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
            child: _InputEmail(),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
            child: _RfcHomoclave(),
            //child: Expanded(child: _SelectRfc()),
          ),

        ]);
      }
    }
```

> Aqui Hay dos Input perfectamente alineados, pero cuando salt ala validación en uno de ellos
> el qu etiene la validacion se espande a toda la Row se mueve para arriba mientras el otro campo se queda en el mismo sitio

```
    class _RfcHomoclave extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
      const _SelectRfc({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      ConsumerState<_SelectRfc> createState() => _RfcHomoclave();
    }

    class _RfcHomoclaveS extends ConsumerState<_RfcHomoclave> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final rfc =
            ref.watch(addressFormNotifierProvider.select((state) => state.rfc));

        final homocode = ref
            .watch(addressFormNotifierProvider.select((state) => state.homocode));

        return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: CCTextInputGeneric(
                enabled: false,
                initialValue: rfc.value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  ref.read(addressFormNotifierProvider.notifier).changeRfc(value);
                },
                hintText: rfc.value.isNotEmpty ? rfc.value : 'RFC',
                labelText: 'RFC*',
                errorText: rfc.invalid
                    ? (rfc.error as RfcValidationError).description
                    : null,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: CCTextInputGeneric(
                initialValue: homocode.value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  ref
                      .read(addressFormNotifierProvider.notifier)
                      .changeHomocode(value);
                },
                hintText: homocode.value.isNotEmpty ? homocode.value : 'Homoclave',
                labelText: 'Homoclave*',
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                  UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                      RegExp(RegexFormat.notSpecialCharactersNotBlank())),
                ],
                errorText: homocode.invalid
                    ? (homocode.error as HomoCodeValidationError).description
                    : null,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

> Probé quitar el Expanded por  Container con valor fijo, pero cuando reduzco la pantalla se desborda

```
    return Row(
          children: [
    -        /* Expanded (
    +        Container(
    +          //color: Colors.blue,
    +          //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
    +          height: 100,
    +          width: 150,
              child: CCTextInputGeneric(
                enabled: false,
                initialValue: rfc.value,
    @@ -233,8 +198,12 @@ class _SelectRfcS2 extends ConsumerState<_SelectRfc2> {
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
    -        ),*/
    -        Expanded(
    +        ),
    +        Container(
    +          //color: Colors.blue,
    +          //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
    +          height: 100,
    +          width: 150,
              child: CCTextInputGeneric(
                initialValue: homocode.value,
                onChanged: (value) {
```

Comment: podrías agregar screenshots quizás

Answer (score 0):

no soy un experto, pero según yo si quitas el expanded y no usas nada, tus inputs por defecto se expanden al tamaño disponible, si aun asi el error sigue, deberias intentar usar un SizedBox que es igual que el container, le especificas el tamaño del ancho mediante el Mediaquery.

quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
  SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
            child://tu Widget ,
          ),
```

El mediaquery toma el tamaño de la pantalla y digamos que si es de 2000 pixeles fisicos, y lo divides entre 4, te quedan 500, si alteras el tamaño  de la interfaz, se alteraria en base al ancho de la pantalla, entonces solo quedaria que prubes cual division te es más adecuado.

Espero te sirva y mucha suerte.

Comment: Excelente respuesta , puede ser una buena opción

Answer (score 0):

> Les comparto como se soluciono, por si alguien tiene un problema parecido ,
> Se Coloco en un Row en el child como Widget con los dos Expanded. Alco asi:

```
            return Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        //color: Colors.amber,
                        height: 100,
                        child: CCTextInputGeneric(
                          enabled: false,
                          initialValue: rfc.value,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            ref.read(addressFormNotifierProvider.notifier).changeRfc(value);
                          },
                          hintText: rfc.value.isNotEmpty ? rfc.value : 'RFC',
                          labelText: 'RFC*',
                          errorText: rfc.invalid
                              ? (rfc.error as RfcValidationError).description
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        //color: Colors.amber,
                        height: 100,
                        child: CCTextInputGeneric(
                          initialValue: homocode.value,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            ref
                                .read(addressFormNotifierProvider.notifier)
                                .changeHomocode(value);
                          },
                          hintText:
                              homocode.value.isNotEmpty ? homocode.value : 'Homoclave',
                          labelText: 'HC*', // 'Homoclave*'
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                            UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                RegExp(RegexFormat.notSpecialCharactersNotBlank())),
                          ],
                          errorText: homocode.invalid
                              ? (homocode.error as HomoCodeValidationError).description
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
```